# Expectation related to renewal measure

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d. random variables, and $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Assume that $0 < \mathbf{E}(X_1) < \infty$ (but don't assume that the $X_i$ are $>0$). Let $N$ be the almost surely finite stopping time $N=\inf \{ n ; S_n>0 \}$. Let $A \subset \mathbf R$ be some Borel set. We are interested in
$$ U = \mathbf{E} \left[ \sum_{n \geq N} \mathbf{1}_A (S_n) \right] = \mathbf{E} \left[ \sum_{n \geq N} \mathbf{1}_{A-S_N} (S_n-S_N) \right] $$

Now it is tempting to say that $S_n-S_N$ has the same distribution as $S_{n-N}$ when $n \geq N$, so that if we let, for any real $a$, $\mu(a)=\mathbf{E}\left[ \sum_{n \geq 0} \mathbf{1}_{A-a} (S_n) \right]$, we have in fact
$$ U = \mathbf{E} [\mu(S_N)]$$

I did not succeed in making this derivation formal. Could you help me? I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me which part of the derivation you regard as insufficiently formal -- the claim that $S_n-S_N$ has the same distribution as $S_{n-N}$, or your deductions from that?

Comment: The phrase "$S_n-S_N$ has the same distribution as $S_{n-N}$ when $n \geq N$" is meaningless, I think, because $N$ is a random variable. You can't say "I pick $n \geq N$ and I consider the random variable $S_n-S_N$", can you?

Comment: The formulation that $S_{N+n}-S_N$ is distributed as $S_n$, for every $n\geqslant0$, might be more rigorous.